# insertAfter multiple elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var group1 = $('#coach-group-group1');
var group2Title = $('#title-group2').clone();
group2Title.remove();
var group2 = $('#coach-group-group2').clone();
group2.remove();
$(group2, group2Title).insertAfter(group1);
```

.. doesn't seem to work, it only inserts first of the two elements provided, not the second, and there are no errors in the console either.

How do I insert multiple elements, in order, one after the other using `insertAfter`?

Comment: You're removing the elements you just cloned...

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to be `removing` elements, do it after you need them :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(group2, group2Title)` doesn't create a set of two DOM elements. The second argument [is usually the *context*](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) in which the first argument is evaluated, but if the first argument is not a selector, then the second argument is simply ignored.

It seems you are looking for [`.add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
group2.add(group2Title).inserAfter(...);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QWGzd/)

But I think your intentions would be clearer if you used [`.after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
group1.after(group2, group2Title);
```

---

FWIW, it doesn't make sense to call `.remove` on those elements because they are not in the document.

Comment: They *are* in the document, I need to rearrange without editing the markup.

Comment: @Nimbuz: No, `group2Title` etc, refer to the **cloned** nodes. They are not contained in the document, they are *clones* of the ones that are in the document.